Equivalent characterizations for a topological space being a graph
How can we show that for a topological space $X$, the following two conditions are equivalent? I believe that they're both characterizations of what might reasonably be called a graph.
Condition 1: For every point $x$ of $X$, one of the following two should hold:

There is an open neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ and a homeomorphism between $U$ and $(0, 1)$.

There is an open neighbourhood $U$ of $x$. Additionally, there is some $n \in \mathbb{N}_{\geq 0}$. Now let $I_n = (0, 1]$. Let $Y$ be the quotient of $\coprod I_n$ identifying all the $1 \in I_n$. Then we want there to be a homeomorphism between $U$ and $Y$ taking $x$ to $1$.


Condition 2: We want to have index sets $A$, $B$, $C$ and $D$ as well as maps $p: A \times \{0, 1\} \to D$ and $q: B \to D$. Each $p^{-1}(\{d\})$ and $q^{-1}(\{d\})$ should be finite. Now take a copy $I_a = [0, 1]$ for each $a \in A$, $I_b = (0, 1]$ for each $b \in B$ and $I_c = (0, 1)$ for each $c \in C$. Consider the quotient $Y$ of all the $I_a$, $I_b$ and $I_c$ where we identify, for each fixed $d \in D$, the points $\epsilon \in I_a$ for $(a, \epsilon) \in p^{-1}(\{b\})$ and $1 \in I_b$ for $b \in q^{-1}(\{d\})$. The condition is that $X$ should be homeomorphic to such a $Y$.

I'm having some trouble grasping your Condition 2. However, it might help to know that a topological graph is typically just defined as a 1-dimensional cell complex. See pages 5 and 6 of Allen Hatcher's "Algebraic Topology" (available for free online!).

@JMM I was essentially trying to write down that the space is a collection of some $[0, 1]$'s, $(0, 1]$'s and $(0, 1)$'s glued along their boundary points.

@JMM I'll have a look at Hatcher's book.
